# Gitlab Omnibus: how to redirect all requests to another domain

Tags: redirect, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I migrated my Gitlab to a new domain. I'd like to redirect all HTTP requests from the old URL to the new one. Both domains currently point to the same server (using `A` DNS records).

I use Gitlab Omnibus package, with the bundled nginx install.
How to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf`:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name old-gitlab.mydomain.com;
  rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://new-gitlab.mydomain.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

(if the `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` path does not exist, go ahead and create it)

Now edit the configuration file at `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to add the following line:

```
nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf;"
```

Finally, run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` to rewrite the nginx configuration and restart nginx.

Comment: +1 because you pointed me in the `custom_nginx_config` direction. From documentation I hadn't understood that you could run both custom and bundled config at the same time.