# Gitlab Omnibus: how to rewrite URLs with bundled nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

## Current configuration

I migrated my GitLab to a new server. As part of the migration, some repositories were reorganized. We have a website that links directly to *raw* and *blob* files on GitLab. I'd like to redirect all HTTPS requests from the old URLs to the new ones, for these *raw* and *blob* files.

I use Gitlab Omnibus package, with the bundled nginx install. I based myself on the accepted answer to this question: [Gitlab Omnibus: how to redirect all requests to another domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33601173/gitlab-omnibus-how-to-redirect-all-requests-to-another-domain), which in turn refers to the official GitLab documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-settings-into-the-nginx-config.

1. Create nginx config directory, because it did not yet exist:

   `sudo mkdir -p /etc/nginx/conf.d/`
2. Create `/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf`:

.

```
server {
  server_name gitlab.itextsupport.com;
  rewrite ^\/itext7\/samples\/(blob|raw)\/master\/(?!samples\/)(.*)$ https://$server_name/itext7/samples/$1/master/samples/$2 permanent;
}
```

3. Edit the configuration file at `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to add the following line:

   `nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf;"`
4. Rewrite the nginx configuration:

   `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
5. Restart the bundled nginx:

   `sudo gitlab-ctl restart nginx`
6. Verify that the bundled nginx includes the redirect file:

   `sudo grep 'redirect.conf' /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`

## Testing the configuration

```
curl -I https://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_05_SignWithBEID.java
```

## Expected result

`/samples` gets inserted after `/blob/master`. I expect to see a 301 rewrite to `https://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/tutorial/blob/master/samples/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_05_SignWithBEID.java`

## Actual result

200 OK on the unmodified URL.

## Ugly hack

Add this line to `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf` and restart the bundled nginx:

```
rewrite ^\/itext7\/samples\/(blob|raw)\/master\/(?!samples\/)(.*)$ https://$server_name/itext7/samples/$1/master/samples/$2 permanent;
```

By doing it this way, I have verified that my actual rewrite rule itself is correct.

Drawback: this line will be lost every time `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` is run.

## Question

What do I need to change to make the URL rewrite work as expected? Without the ugly hack?

## Additional information

When I run `sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx -T`, I see two `server { }` blocks. My working theory so far is that nginx is picking up only the first server block, and ignoring the second one. If I could find a way to merge both server blocks, in a way that is compatible with the configuration file `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, then my problem is most likely solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it looks like the answer was staring me in the face in `gitlab.rb`. One line above `nginx['custom_nginx_config']`, there is `nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config']`. I put the include statement there, and removed the `server {}` brackets around the rewrite rules. This is also described in the GitLab documentation at https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/nginx.html#inserting-custom-nginx-settings-into-the-gitlab-server-block:

> This inserts the defined string into the end of the server block of `/var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf`.

So this is what I did:

1. In `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`, comment out the `nginx['custom_nginx_config']` line and add:

   `nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf;"`
2. In `/etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf`, only keep the rewrite line on its own:

   `rewrite ^\/itext7\/samples\/(blob|raw)\/master\/(?!samples\/)(.*)$ https://$server_name/itext7/samples/$1/master/samples/$2 permanent;`
3. Reconfigure GitLab:

   `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`
4. Restart nginx:

   `sudo gitlab-ctl restart nginx`
5. Verify the nginx configuration:

   `sudo /opt/gitlab/embedded/sbin/nginx -p /var/opt/gitlab/nginx -T | tail -n 20`

.

```
nginx: the configuration file /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/conf.d/redirect.conf:
rewrite ^\/itext7\/samples\/(blob|raw)\/master\/(?!samples\/)(.*)$ https://$server_name/itext7/samples/$1/master/samples/$2 permanent;

# configuration file /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/nginx-status.conf:
server  {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8060;
    server_name localhost;
    location /nginx_status {
      stub_status on;
      server_tokens off;
      access_log off;
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny all;
    }
}
```

6. Verify the URL rewrite:

   `curl -I https://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/tutorial/blob/master/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_05_SignWithBEID.java`

.

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 27 Sep 2018 11:32:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 178
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itext/tutorial/blob/master/samples/signatures/src/main/java/signatures/chapter4/C4_05_SignWithBEID.java
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

---

One thing I am still curious about:

- The `rewrite` line ended up *outside* the `server{}` block.
- The `rewrite` line uses the `$server_name` variable.
- The `$server_name` variable is defined *inside* the `server{}` block.

Is that visually confusing because of how the weird way included statements are displayed by `nginx -T`? Is the `rewrite` line really *inside* the `server{}` block even if it appears to be *outside*? Why are things oft not as they appear to be, and why is GitLab documentation written in a hermetic language? Alas, these ponderings may forever remain unanswered.